# Read .doc file in flask api

Tags: python, flask, docx

```
@app.route('/parse', methods=['POST'])
def parse():
    response = request.files['file']
    file_name = response.filename
```

Wanted to save this as doc, docx, pdf or txt file. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with a TXT file easily. Here is the documentation on how to read&write to files: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Reading doc as txt using read() function gives me asci characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice post that explains this in details: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask
Here is the core.

`index.html`:

```
  <body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="doc_file" accept=".doc,.docx"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
```

`app.py`:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    uploaded_file = request.files['doc_file']
    if uploaded_file.filename != '':
        uploaded_file.save(uploaded_file.filename)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

# A welcome message to test our server
@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Return the main page."""
    # stedin_map = get_map()
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the [link](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask), that really helped.